# Absurd and jerky movement of scene while scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

When the scene moves, it moves (sometimes not always) in an absurd and jerky way that leads to irritation. The following code has been used to move the scene:

```
//NAVIGATION TOWARDS X AND Y WhenEver and how ever you want

            if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY))    //Scroll in x
            {
                //CCLOG(@"yScrlFlag=%d",yScrlFlag);
                if(diffX > 0)
                {
                    xScrlFlag=1;
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-3112-self.parent.position.x)/950)
                                                               position:ccp((-3112-self.position.x),self.parent.position.y)]];
                    [resetPosition setIsEnabled:YES];
                    [resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-3112-self.parent.position.x)/950) 
                                                                 position:ccp((3112+self.position.x+70),resetPosition.position.y)]];
                    //[self.parent.menuButton setIsEnabled:NO];
                }
                else
                {
                    xScrlFlag=0;                        
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-self.parent.position.x/950) 
                                                               position:ccp(0,self.parent.position.y)]];
                    //[resetPosition setIsEnabled:YES];
                    [resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-self.parent.position.x/950) 
                                                                 position:ccp(141,resetPosition.position.y)]];
                }
            }
            else  //Scroll in y
            {                       
                if(diffY < 0)
                {
                    [resetPosition setIsEnabled:YES];
                    //CCLOG(@"MOVING PARENT BY=%f",(-self.position.y));
                    //CCLOG(@"self.parent.position BEFORE MOVE=(%f, %f)",self.parent.position.x,self.parent.position.y);
                    //CCLOG(@"resetPosition.position BEFORE MOVE=(%f, %f)",resetPosition.position.x,resetPosition.position.y);
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/650) 
                                                               position:ccp(self.parent.position.x,(-self.position.y))]];

                    //Working
                    [resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/650) 
                                                                 position:ccp(resetPosition.position.x, 280-(-self.position.y))]];

                    //CCLOG(@"self.parent.position AFTER MOVE=(%f, %f)",self.parent.position.x,self.parent.position.y);
                    //CCLOG(@"resetPosition.position BEFORE MOVE=(%f, %f)",resetPosition.position.x,resetPosition.position.y);
                }
                else
                {   
                    //CCLOG(@"yScrlFlag");
                    yScrlFlag=0;
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/950) 
                                                               position:ccp(self.parent.position.x,0)]];

                    [resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/949) 
                                                                 position:ccp(resetPosition.position.x,280)]];
                }

            }
```

What I want is all time smoothness in the movement of scene. As the code shows, it moves the *scene* in both horizontal and vertical direction. And the basic problem occurs when one (any) `sprite` in the scene is mobilized, and the scene starts scrolling. It behaves in a jerky way in that case too (possibly more so than in the normal case). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try CCFollow instead of doing everything manually:

[CCFollow](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_c_follow.html)

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer.  I saw your comment a couple of hours ago but I am not feeling very well today.  CCFollow is really simple.  If you have a sprite that you wish the view to stay with it is as simple as this:  `[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:myShipImage]];`

There may be other ways to use it but this is the only way I have ever used it.  I hope that helps.

Comment: In that code, myShipImage is a sprite.  It has a box2d body connected to it but that doesn't matter.  The camera follows along smoothly.  If you need UI elements and whatever else on top that don't move or jerk around then try adding a CCParallax node as a child and add any UI elements (or whatever) to that, using a parallax ratio of ccp(0.0, 0.0)

Comment: 'Get well soon', thank for the response 'any way', I'll work with it.